# Aesthetics error in a bar chart (ggplot, R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a bar chart with a gradient that goes from yellow to red.
However, I keep getting **"Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): y and fill"**.

This code worked perfectly with a nearly identical data frame, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. On another website they suggested picking the filling of each bar manually, i.e. fill=c("red", "...",) etc, but that would go against the idea of using a gradient.

Here's the code, below you can find a dput of the data frame if it helps:

**Code:**

```
plot <- df %>% 
  mutate(name1 = "Average unemployment rate") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Region, 
             y=Avg_Unemployment_rate, 
             fill=Avg_Unemployment_rate)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high = "red") + 
  labs(y = "Unemployment Rate (%)", x="") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~name1) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,6), expand=0)
```

**dput**

```
structure(list(Region = structure(c(10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("South East", "South West", "London", 
"East of England", "East Midlands", "West Midlands", "Yorkshire and The Humber", 
"North East", "North West", "England"), class = "factor"), Avg_Unemployment_rate = structure(c(4.05052633258656, 
3.21824018447441, 3.05119829228833, 4.7077689256265, 3.44297331188711, 
4.23448912295878, 4.67588411516106, 4.45220611226308, 5.69591652090698, 
4.06868093338517, 0.325604322866634, 0.36720756911479, 0.595564571651833, 
0.538576162975837, 0.467897513070492, 0.427419900308709, 0.378156613118954, 
0.469553277333867, 0.537080804732578, 0.33118433822167), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("mean", "sd"))), SD = c(0.325604322866634, 
0.36720756911479, 0.595564571651833, 0.538576162975837, 0.467897513070492, 
0.427419900308709, 0.378156613118954, 0.469553277333867, 0.537080804732578, 
0.33118433822167)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Duck's output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- cbind(df[,c(1,3)],df$Avg_Unemployment_rate)
#Plot
df %>% 
  mutate(name1 = "Average unemployment rate") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Region, 
             y=mean, 
             fill=mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high = "red") + 
  labs(y = "Unemployment Rate (%)", x="") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~name1) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,6), expand=0)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Heyy! Just tried, but the output looks pretty odd. Updating my first post with the output now

Comment: Just saw your edit. Ok I'll try changing it to a data frame first then

Comment: @Lactuca I have added an update for you. Please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: I changed the table to a numeric class and it works! Thanks a lot for your edited code too :D

Comment: @Lactuca Awesome, a pleasure helping you. Consider accepting the answer if you think it helped in your issue. Kind regards!

Comment: Sorry had to wait for a bit before accepting it! Guess it's because I accepted one earlier